# How to locate element which is called after JS script is executed and displayed

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="inline-check">
span class="ic-check" style="display: inline;">
```

Above is sample of the HTML which i am trying to find using any type of locater. It is text box which accept numbers and then shows a green tick mark that the input is accepted. Element `style ="display: none;"` turn to inline in HTML but when tried to look through xpath it is always visible like above.

I have tried finding the element using `xpath` and getting size of it and verify if it come as True or False.
but as the element is always present it passes even if the green tick is not displayed. 
What technique should be used to find such elements.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your problem. It sounds like you're always finding it (despite it being hidden), but you're asking for a way to find it? Can you reformulate?

Comment: If i inspect element in HTML  it changes from 'none' to 'inline' as soon as the criteria is met ( adding phone number) , but when i am trying to find it through 'xpath' it shows as above it does not change. So it is always displayed. You can take any example , this is similar to adding an email address where JS scripts verifies that customer adds xyz@abc.com this syntax and then shows green mark of acceptance. I am trying to check if that green mark is displayed in automation

Comment: Well, the element is always present in the DOM yes, so you can still target it using CSS or Xpath selectors. It's just not rendered in the view.

Comment: would you please provide me sample of how to do it. below is my xpath
d.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='******']/div[1]/div/span[@style='display: inline;']")

Comment: Instead of writing style inline (bad practice), use a "hidden" class or something. Then check if the element has the `hidden` class. If it does, it means it's hidden.

Comment: I am testing this text box where if i enter a number i need to verify if the check mark is displayed or not , that is my test scenario. I am not able to related your comment to my objective.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `isDisplayed()` method from WebElement https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed-- ? It's basically a built in function that checks the style attribute.

So you could try doing something like this:

```
WebElement checkmark = driver.findElement(By.className("ic-check"));
assertTrue(checkmark.isDisplayed());
```

Hope this helps.